# How can I access the elements of a string list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a String `X` that is a List and I want to access its elements.
example:

```
"[('here', 29), ('negative', 1.0)]"
```

How can I access the `'here'`, `29` and `'negative'`?

Comment: This looks like a python list containing two python tuples to my eyes. You might look into how you are importing this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
v1 <- strsplit(x, "[[:punct:] ]")[[1]]
v1[nzchar(v1)][1:3]
#[1] "here"     "29"       "negative"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `stringr::str_split`:

```
library(stringr)
x <- "[('here', 29), ('negative', 1.0)]"
v1 <- str_split(x, "[[:punct:] ]")[[1]]
v1[nchar(v1)>1]
#[1] "here"     "29"       "negative"
```